# NSolve produces no solution to a nonlinear system

Tags: equation-solving

This NSolve code on a system of nonlinear equations produces no output:

```
NSolve[
 {
  (a*b)/(a*b + c*d + a*d + b*c) == 0.8,
  (c*d)/(a*b + c*d + a*d + b*c) == 0.1,
  (a*b)/(a*b + e*f + a*f + b*e) == 0.2,
  (e*f)/(a*b + e*f + a*f + b*e) == 0.2,
  (c*d)/(c*d + e*f + c*f + d*e) == 0.1,
  (e*f)/(c*d + e*f + c*f + d*e) == 0.8
   && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0 && f > 0
  }, 
{a, b, c, d, e, f}
 ]
```

Is there something I could change to get a more informative response back?

Thanks.

Comment: The result is informative. Check the 4th bullet point under Details on the NSolve doc page.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {
  (a*b)/(a*b + c*d + a*d + b*c) == 4/5, 
  (c*d)/(a*b + c*d + a*d + b*c) == 1/10, 
  (a*b)/(a*b + e*f + a*f + b*e) == 1/5, 
  (e*f)/(a*b + e*f + a*f + b*e) == 1/5, 
  (c*d)/(c*d + e*f + c*f + d*e) == 1/10, 
  (e*f)/(c*d + e*f + c*f + d*e) == 4/5, 
  a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0, f > 0};

vars = Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]];
```

[`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) indicates that there is no solution (see documentation for meaning of `{ }` as a result)

```
NSolve[eqns, vars]

(* {} *)
```

[`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) indicates that there is no solution

```
FindInstance[eqns, vars]

(* {} *)
```

[`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) indicates that there is no solution, i.e., minimum value is not approximately zero.

```
nmr = NMinimize[
  Join[{Total[(#[[1]] - #[[-1]] & /@ eqns[[1 ;; 6]])^2]}, eqns[[7 ;;]]], vars]

(* {0.0163241, {a -> 4.47621, b -> 1.38793, c -> 0.322225, d -> 0.249771, 
  e -> 1.79054, f -> 3.46971}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.